# Scroll jumping with nib custom cell and autolayout (ios 8 swift - UITableview)

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I've implemented the custom cell with autolayout from this reference: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

In my cell I have an imageView and 5 labels with dynamic content.

What I want to achieve is something like the feed from Facebook where in every cell image size differs. I have metadata for the image sizes.

I tried using estimatedHeightForRow and given some average height.

Everything works fine in the layout but it jumps while scrolling.

How can I improve my tableview scroll performance?

Comment: Are you doing any background tasks during scrolling? For example network requests or other stuff?

Comment: I am downloading image asynchronously      let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
               self.ImageFeedView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.cueData.attachments[0].URL);}
self.ImageFeedView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.cueData.attachments[0].URL, completed:block)

Comment: iOS8 automatic dimension is buggy, use iOS7 variant - https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout

Comment: Are you doind anything async in the background? Where do you get the text for each cell from? Isn't this also a network call? (maybe some JSON WepApi?)

Comment: @Darko I had the data in my collection object(NSMutableArray)

Comment: Please try heightForRowAtIndexPath instead of estimatedHeightForRow.

Comment: calculating height is again a problem because it has  5 labels and image.

Answer (score 1):

You have posted this code in some of your comments:

```
    let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {
        (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in
        self.ImageFeedView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.cueData.attachments[0].URL);
    }

    self.ImageFeedView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.cueData.attachments[0].URL, completed:block)
```

You are setting the image two times. First with:

```
self.ImageFeedView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.cueData.attachments[0].URL, completed: block)
```

And then again, the same image in the completion block. That's unnecessary and *could* lead to stuttering. Just remove the block and do this:

```
self.ImageFeedView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.cueData.attachments[0].URL)
```

The stuttering should be better now. (or even resolved, please try)

Comment: I had commented the setting image and giving image from local but still scroll is jumpy

Comment: @Kirankoneti I had the same problem. Did you get solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Table sometimes twitches when upload large images. Maybe try to decode received photos:

```
UIImage *anImage = ...  // Assume this exists.
CGImageRef originalImage = (CGImageRef)anImage;
assert(originalImage != NULL);

CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(originalImage));
CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData);
if (imageData != NULL) {
  CFRelease(imageData);
}
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(CGImageGetWidth(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetHeight(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetBytesPerRow(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetColorSpace(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetBitmapInfo(originalImage),
                                 imageDataProvider,
                                 CGImageGetDecode(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetShouldInterpolate(originalImage),
                                 CGImageGetRenderingIntent(originalImage));
if (imageDataProvider != NULL) {
  CGDataProviderRelease(imageDataProvider);
}

// Do something with the image.

CGImageRelease(image);
```

The image received from CGImageCreate() is already decoded, which is exactly what we need. All that’s left is to wrap this code in NSOperation to execute it in background and finally send the results to the main thread. Using +[UIImage imageWithCGImage:] we get UIImage from the resulting CGImage and assign it to the required UIImageView right during scrolling. The animation works flawlessly.

Comment: Do you have this function in swift?